# Grails test-app load beans from applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring, grails, spring-mvc, integration-testing

I have Grails application that defines beans in `WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. (`resources.groovy` not used for reasons that are not part of this topic). When I try to run `grails test-app`, Spring can't inject beans into services, therefore tests are breaking. How can I get `grails test-app` to load beans from `applicationContext.xml` as well?

Comment: After lots of trying to get things working with applicationContext.xml, i moved all of my bean definitions to resources.grooy, so both run-app and test-app are recognizing them.